# Query for "Related Tags", that appear together frequently

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

I am trying to find out the tags that appear frequently together for a given tag.

For example, [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) will appear frequently with [python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3) and [nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nltk) will appear together with [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) and so on.

So by running a query for [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), I want to get the more frequently used tags with Pandas.

Comment: Did you know that clicking on a tag on Stack Overflow will show you a list of the top tags used with that tag? It’s under “related tags”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1237615?tagname=pandas) does that for you.

It is basically joining the PostTags table twice, one to get the PostIds for the tag you want to use as a selection and then again to find the other tagid-s. Joining with the Tags table is trivial so you can show the name of the tag.

```
select tt.tagname, count(*) [count] 
from posttags pt -- tags on posts
inner join tags st on st.id = pt.tagid -- selection tag
inner join posttags ptt on ptt.postid = pt.postid -- other tags
inner join tags tt on tt.id =  ptt.tagid -- other tag names
where st.tagname = ##tagname:string?pandas##
and tt.tagname <> ##tagname:string?pandas##
group by tt.tagname
order by count(*) desc
```

This is what the top result looks like:

[image]

You can somewhat verify the result if you look at the [top users for a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/topusers) as that has the related tags list in the right side bar as well.